# PHP check if field is empty

Tags: php, html, field

I'm doing a register form and I'm trying to write a code that will show error if user does not fill all fields. It works okay but for some reason it works only if I enter email. If I leave all fields empty and click register, I don't get any error and with all fields empty my cursor goes to email field and gets activated (this field) when I click register button.
Something is wrong with this email but I cannot find any problem, so what is wrong?

PHP source code:

```
if(empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['lname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $error="Fill all fields!";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
  <input style="margin-top:10px" type="text" value="First Name" name="fname" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = '';}" />

  <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="lname" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Last Name') {this.value = '';}" />

  <input type="email" value="Adres e-mail" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Adres e-mail';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Adres e-mail') {this.value = '';}" />

  <p><input type="password" value="Password" name="password" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value = '';}" /></p>

  <button type="submit" name="submit"> Register</button> </br>
  </br>

</form>
```

Comment: What's the status of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Because the other fields are `type="text"` and empty are considered as empty strings `""`. Try to check also if they are not empty. ;)

For example:

```
if(isset($_POST["fname"]) && (strlen($_POST["fname"]) > 0) && isset($_POST["lname"]) && (strlen($_POST["lname"]) > 0) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    //your code
}
```

For email and password you can skip empty I guess if you make them required in HTML5.

Comment: Don't rely on client side validation. `isset` and `!empty` are basically the same thing. `That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false`-http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: hi chris85, should be better now I guess...just checking the length

Comment: @chris85 isset and ! empty not the same thing

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera Yea, I said `basically` (as the manual states).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are empty. They will either be undefined or `""`. Use `print_r($_POST['name'])` for each one and see what they come back as. Then you will see if they are empty or not.

Comment: As in... print_r($_POST['fname']);

Answer (score 0):

The `onblur` and `onfocus` events make the `value` of each input always populated so when you submit each field has its default value, or what you changed it to. A better solution to this would be using the `placeholder` attribute. This will keep the `value`s empty until a user populates them.

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
  <input style="margin-top:10px" type="text" value="First Name" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />  
  <input type="email" value="Adres e-mail" name="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail" />
  <p><input type="password" value="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /></p>
  <button type="submit" name="submit"> Register</button> </br>
  </br>
</form>
```

This also should function better for the password field because I suspect you previously had the `password` as 8 bullet points.

Server side you could verify this was the cause by outputting the `$_POST` array with `var_dump` or `print_r`, or by iterating over it `foreach($_POST as $name => value)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your PHP Code is Correct. but your HTML Form have some Technical Error. you must set **`placeholder`** attribute for show Field name in input boxs, becasue when onBlur event was run, the value was set for field and string sent to server, and that NOT Empty ! in this way your PHP code does't work for check empty values. the secondary work you must do, check field in client side for not empty by easily set **`required`** attribute for each input element. I wrote correct html tags that you must use.

```html
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
      <input style="margin-top:10px" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required />

      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required />

      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail" required />

      <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /></p>

      <button type="submit" name="submit"> Register</button> </br>
      </br>

    </form>
```

for PHP code you can use Foreach as simply way :

```php
$error="";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $error="Fill all fields!";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you must you **placeholder** instead of **value**.

```
<form action="index3.php" method="POST" >

    <input style="margin-top:10px" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname"
    onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'First Name';}"
    onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'First Name') {this.placeholder = '';}"  />

    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname"
    onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Last Name';}"
    onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Last Name') {this.placeholder = '';}"  />

    <input type="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail" name="email"
    onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Adres e-mail';}"
    onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Adres e-mail') {this.placeholder = '';}"  />

    <p><input type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="password"
    onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Password';}"
    onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Password') {this.placeholder = '';}"  /></p>

    <button type="submit" name="submit"> Register</button> </br></br>

</form>
```

Comment: Your answer is still using the `value`s.